# I'm trying to figure out if GoogleNews is allowed to webscrape

Tags: r, web-scraping

I'm using **paths_allowed** function from the package **robotstxt** 
to find out whether data can be scraped from a particular website, in my case https://news.google.com/?hl=en-IN&gl=IN&ceid=IN%3Aen, but everytime I do this I'm getting error

```
library(robotstxt)
paths_allowed(paths = "https://news.google.com/?hl=en-IN&gl=IN&ceid=IN%3Aen")
```

The error message is like this:

```
news.google.com                      Error in if (is_http) { : argument is of length zero
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just using the `httr` package and posting a `GET` request to `https://news.google.com/robots.txt` to get the information we need:

```
a <- httr::GET("https://news.google.com/robots.txt")
httr::content(a)
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
Disallow: /search?
Allow: /$
Allow: /?
Allow: /nwshp$
Allow: /news$
Allow: /news/$
Allow: /news/?gl=
Allow: /news/?hl=
Allow: /news/?ned=
Allow: /about$
Allow: /about?
Allow: /about/
Allow: /topics/
Allow: /publications/
Allow: /stories/
Allow: /swg/

User-agent: Googlebot
Disallow: /topics/
Disallow: /publications/
Disallow: /stories/
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but is there any logical error in my code. Because I saw this same code from a Youtube video and he didn't face any issues.

Comment: Hmm... Try `paths = c(the-url)`

Comment: Putting your url inside c()... I haven't worked with that package so not too sure.